# Pushing new mailbox limits for Exchange 2003 accounts

Tags: exchange-2003, mailbox

There is this problem that I have every time I set up an account for a user on Exchange 2003. After I update the Mailbox limit to unlimited in the Exchange tab in the user preferences it does not seem to update right away.

I remember reading somewhere that it takes several hours for the change to update in the database. I also remember typing in some terminal command that pushed the new updates immediately.

What is that command, and why is it so difficult to find the answer to this problem on Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is stored in active directory, and may not replicate immediately.  Even if it is replicated exchange only updates this information periodically.

Here is your fix: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=327378

Basically a few regedits.